# Assign Value Rails Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, ruby-on-rails-4

At this time I need to assign a value to a column in my DB
I'm working with Rails 4.0

I Have this link in the view:

```
link_to 'Finalizar', note_finalizar_path(note), class: 'btn btn-success btn-mini'
```

And i have a method this way in the controller:

```
def finalizar
    @note = Note.where(:id => Note.id).first
    if @note.update_column(:estado, false)
        redirect_to notes_path, :notice => "OK"
    else
        redirect_to notes_path, :notice => "NO"
    end
end
```

The thing is that when I clicked on the button i got this error:

```
undefined method `id' for #Class:0xa675070>
```

Sorry for my english is not my native language and thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need something like this:

**link**

```
link_to 'Finalizar', note_finalizar_path(note), class: 'btn btn-success btn-mini'
```

**controller**

```
def finalizar
  @note = Note.find(params[:note_id])
  @note.update_attribute(:estado, false)
  if @note.estado
    redirect_to notes_path, :notice => "OK"
  else
    redirect_to notes_path, :notice => "NO"
  end
end
```

Comment: I did what you told me but now the problem is
   Couldn't find Note without an ID

Comment: post your logs and I'll look into it, server logs, also I edited my answer at link_to

Comment: The beginning of the log is this
Started GET "/notes/5/finalizar" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-25 10:02:29 -0500
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by NotesController#finalizar as HTML
  Parameters: {"note_id"=>"5"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 17ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Note without an ID:
  activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:266:in `find_with_ids'

Comment: use `@note = Note.find(params[:note_id])` in the controller